# np.array() on array of spectrograms

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to prepare a dataset of spectrograms for machine learning and I'm trying to use np.array() on an array of spectrograms. However, the function throws

```
could not broadcast input array from shape (128,400,1) into shape (128,)
```

This is the code I use to load the spectrograms and all:

```
    class Audio:
    def __init__(self, file_path, label) -> None:
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.label = label

import librosa
import numpy as np
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
from tqdm import tqdm
import os
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

def load_spectrogram(file_path, max_len=128):
    audio, sr = librosa.load(file_path, sr=None)
    sampling_rate = 16000
    window_size_sec = 0.025
    hop_size_sec = 0.01

    window_size = int(sampling_rate * window_size_sec)
    hop_size = int(sampling_rate * hop_size_sec)

    n_fft = 2 ** int(np.ceil(np.log2(window_size)))  # nearest power of 27
    global time_steps
    time_steps = (audio.shape[0] - n_fft) // hop_size + 1

    spectrogram = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=audio, sr=sampling_rate, n_fft=n_fft, hop_length=hop_size, n_mels=64)
    spectrogram = librosa.power_to_db(spectrogram, ref=np.max)
    spectrogram = spectrogram.astype(np.float32)
    spectrogram = np.expand_dims(spectrogram, axis=-1)
    print(f'Spectrogram shape before padding: {spectrogram.shape}')
    spectrogram_padded = pad_sequences([spectrogram], maxlen=max_len, padding='post', dtype='float32')
    spectrogram_padded = spectrogram_padded[0]
    spectrogram_padded = spectrogram_padded[:time_steps]  # Truncate to time_steps
    print(f'Spectrogram shape after padding and truncation: {spectrogram_padded.shape}')

    return spectrogram_padded

    def normalize_spectrogram(spectrogram):
        mean = np.mean(spectrogram)
        std = np.std(spectrogram)
        return (spectrogram - mean) / std
    
    def split_data(X, y, test_ratio=0.2):
        num_samples = X.shape[0]
        indices = np.random.permutation(num_samples)
        test_size = int(num_samples * test_ratio)
        test_indices = indices[:test_size]
        train_indices = indices[test_size:]
        X_train, y_train = X[train_indices], y[train_indices]
        X_test, y_test = X[test_indices], y[test_indices]
        return X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test
    
     Audios = []
        tkinter.Tk().withdraw()
        
        folder_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
        for x in tqdm(os.listdir(folder_path)):
            for y in os.listdir(folder_path + "/" + x):
                file = os.path.join(folder_path + "/" + x, y)
                label = os.path.dirname(file).split('/')[-1]
                Audios.append(Audio(file, label))
        
        X = []
        y = []
        max_len = 0
        for audio in Audios:
            spectrogram = load_spectrogram(audio.file_path)
            normalized_spectrogram = normalize_spectrogram(spectrogram)
            X.append(normalized_spectrogram)
            y.append(audio.label)
            max_len = max(max_len, normalized_spectrogram.shape[0])
            print(f"Current max_len: {max_len}")
        
        print(f"Final max_len: {max_len}")
        
        num_accents = len(y)
        X = np.array(X)
        X = pad_sequences(X, maxlen=128, padding='post', dtype='float32')
        y = np.array(y)
        X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = split_data(X, y)
```

But I want to highlight the output of this code:

```
Spectrogram shape before padding: (64, 400, 1)
Spectrogram shape after padding and truncation: (128, 400, 1)
Current max_len: 128
Spectrogram shape before padding: (64, 469, 1)
Spectrogram shape after padding and truncation: (128, 469, 1)
Current max_len: 128
Spectrogram shape before padding: (64, 442, 1)
Spectrogram shape after padding and truncation: (128, 442, 1)
Current max_len: 128
Spectrogram shape before padding: (64, 483, 1)
Spectrogram shape after padding and truncation: (128, 483, 1)
Current max_len: 128
```

This is just a snippet of it but it allows us to understand why the error occurs. Its because the members in the array have different y shapes. I want to know how to fix this since I tried everything and nothing worked.

Comment: There's too much code for me to isolate the problem. Are you trying to create an array of shape `(128, 400+469+442+483, 1)` from several smaller arrays? If so, you might need something like `np.concatenate` instead of `np.array`. If not, please make a much smaller example with dummy arrays and the expected output. Chances are you'll stumble upon the solution along the way. Otherwise feel free to ask :)

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs I want to be able to execute the code but np.array keeps throwing exceptions because all the spectrograms are different.

Comment: You could make a 3d array by `concatenate` on `axis=1`.  That make a (128,n,1) array.  But if you want a (m,128,?,1) shape, you'll have to make all those different 483,442, etc the same - in some way or other.  So you've tried somethings (not **everything** :) ), but we don't know what you've tried, and what the problems were. And we don't really know what your goal is.  What shape and dtype of array do you need?